# Accesar a la ultima fila SQlite en python

Tags: python, sqlite

Gracias a ustedes he ido progresando en mi programa ahora regreso con una pregunta tal vez basica pero tengo dias intentando accesar a la ultima fila de mi base de datos de donde quiero tomar el numero de folio incrementarlo en una unidad y colocarlo en el encabezado de una interfaz grafica para indicar que orden de servicio se está llenando he encontrado en internet que se debe de usar estas lineas 'SELECT * FROM paciente ORDER BY folio DESC LIMIT 1', no he podido encontrar una manera de accesar y desplegarlo.

Anexo el codigo de mi programa (le quite la paja y dejé lo que es la parte central de la pregunta)

```
import sqlite3 # modulo de conexion con sqlite3 

class Product:
    #conexion con la base de datos
    db_lab = 'vitasis.db'

    #contenedor 2 ORDEN DE SERVICIO

    frame2 = LabelFrame(self.wind, text = 'Orden de servicio', labelanchor = N, font = ('Verdana', 16, 'bold'))
    frame2.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 20, ipadx = 30, sticky = W)
    frame2.configure(background = 'gray')
    Label(frame2, text = 'Número de Orden', bg = 'gray').grid(row = 1, column = 1, pady = 3, sticky = W + E)
    self.message1 = Label(frame2, text = '', fg = 'red', font = ('Verdana', 18), bg = 'gray')
    self.message1.grid(row = 2, column = 1, pady = 3, sticky = W + E)  

    self.folio = 6 # quiero quitar este valor predefinido y usar el valor que tiene la ultima fila de mi base de datos e incrementarlo en una unidad para indicar que es una nueva orden de servicio.

    self.message1['text'] = '{}'.format(self.folio)   

    # Ejecutar consulta
def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
    with sqlite3.connect(self.db_lab) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        conn.commit()
    return result

    # Consulta de datos
    query = 'SELECT * FROM paciente ORDER BY folio DESC'
    db_rows = self.run_query(query)
def guardar(self):
    if self.validation():
       query = 'INSERT INTO paciente VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
        parameters =  (self.folio, self.name.get(), self.adress.get(), self.edad.get(), self.sexo.get(), self.prueba.get(), self.prueba2.get(), self.prueba3.get(), self.prueba4.get(), self.prueba5.get(), self.fecha_estudio, self.entrega.get(), self.worker.get(), self.promo.get(), self.subtotal, self.anticipo.get(), self.total, self.saldo_a_pagar)
        self.run_query(query, parameters)
        messagebox.showinfo('Guardar', 'Paciente guardado')
        self.name.delete(0, END)
        self.adress.delete(0, END)
        self.edad.delete(0, END)
        self.sexo.set('---------') 
        self.prueba.set('---------------------------------------------------------------'), 
        self.prueba2.set('N/A') 
        self.prueba3.set('N/A') 
        self.prueba4.set('N/A') 
        self.prueba5.set('N/A')
        self.entrega.delete(0, END)
        self.worker.delete(0, END)
        self.promo.set('---------')
        self.diag.delete(0, END) # no
        self.medico.delete(0, END)
        self.anticipo.delete(0, END)

    else:
       messagebox.showwarning('Atención', 'Por favor rellene todos los campos')
     #   self.get_pacient()
```

En la parte self.folio = 6 es donde quiero que se despliegue mi valor y con el pueda colocarlo como mensaje en mi frame2, despues que se guarde el siguiente numero sea 7 asi indicando que es una nueva orden de servicio, despues guardar todos los datos de mi paciente y cuando se reinicie el programa la siguiente orden de servicio sea 8 dando continuacion a la numeracion tienen alguna sugerencia?
se tiene que definir una nueva funcion? o que tengo que hacer?agradezco su tiempo

Comment: El query deberia ser SELECT folio+1 FROM paciente ORDER BY folio DESC LIMIT 1. Ademas deberia haber un indice por folio. Y tene en cuenta que esto no es para nada multiusuario amigable.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta gbianchi tengo otra pregunta y como lo guardo para que pueda ocuparlo en vez de self.folio = 6?, el indice por folio te refieres a que es un solo numero verdad???

Comment: Lo mio es un comentario, ya que no se como se implementa esto en python. No, de indice te hablo sobre la base de datos. Salvo que esto sea un ejercicio, en ese caso olvidalo.

Comment: bueno aun asi gracias por la aportacion, espero en un futuro resolver este pequeño detalle :S

Comment: Alguien que tenga alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, como comenta @gbianchi la query debería ser:

> SELECT folio+1 FROM paciente ORDER BY folio DESC LIMIT 1

dado que solo te interesa el valor de `folio`. Con `folio + 1` obtienes el siguiente valor al máximo que existe en la columna `folio`. Si quieres el valor de la última ingresada y no el valor que ha de tener la siguiente que ingreses quita la suma.

Para obtener el valor solo necesitas usar `fethone()`. Esto nos **retorna una tupla de un solo elemento o `None` si no existe ningún dato en la tabla**. Para evitar el problema podemos usar un condicional:

```
query = "SELECT folio+1 FROM paciente ORDER BY folio DESC LIMIT 1"
folio = self.run_query(query).fetchone()
if folio is None:
    self.folio = 1     # Valor inicial si no existen datos en la tabla
else:
    self.folio = folio[0]
```

o podemos usar `IFNULL` en la query:

```
query = """
    SELECT IFNULL(
        (SELECT folio + 1
         FROM paciente
         ORDER BY folio DESC
         LIMIT 1), 1)
    """
self.folio =  self.run_query(query).fetchone()[0]
```

Si haces esto en el `__init__` de tu clase, al llamar al método `guardar`, deberás incrementar en uno el valor de `self.folio` de forma manual:

```
class Product:
    db_lab = 'vitasis.db'

    def __init__(self):
        #conexion con la base de datos
        # ...
        query = """
            SELECT IFNULL(
                (SELECT folio + 1
                 FROM paciente
                 ORDER BY folio DESC
                 LIMIT 1), 1)
            """
        self.folio =  self.run_query(query).fetchone()[0]
        # ...

    def guardar(self, n):
        if self.validation:
            # ...
            self.run_query(query, parameters)
            self.folio += 1
            # ...
```

Otra opción seria usas un propiedad y hacer la consulta cada vez que se accede al atributo (si no nos importa la sobrecarga que esto supone, más cuando la query implica ordenar la columna):

```
class Product:
    db_lab = 'vitasis.db'

    @property
    def folio(self):
        query = """
            SELECT IFNULL(
                (SELECT folio + 1
                 FROM paciente
                 ORDER BY folio DESC
                 LIMIT 1), 1)
            """
        return self.run_query(query).fetchone()[0]
```

Para acceder al valor se hace exactamente igual que si definieras el atributo de instancia:

```
self.message1['text'] = '{}'.format(self.folio)
```

Una pequeña nota, cuando usas `with` con tu conexión (administrador de contexto), el commit se hace de forma automática sin necesidad de llamar a `conn.commit()` una vez terminado el bloque. Lo que no se hace es cerrar la conexión, aunque en este caso, dado que es una variable de ámbito local al método, el GC la cerrará en cuanto la función retorne.

Comment: Amigo JFSevilla nuevamente muchas gracias por tu valiosa ayuda en verdad me haz ayudado mucho, usé la 1ra recomendacion que me hiciste me pareció una opcion mas reducida en cuanto a lineas, por lo que veo existen varias maneras de obtener el ultimo registro de la base de datos, lo que me llamó la atencion fue que hiciste el comentario sobre que no importa la sobrecarga cuando se consulta cada vez que se accede al atributo, eso significa que si tengo muchos atributos puede llegar a cargar la memoria del programa?

Comment: Otra pregunta, habia visto la instruccion fetchone() pero desgraciadamente no entendia a que se referia y me llegue a confundir con la instruccion fetchall() pero ahora que lo entiendo esa instruccion toma el registro completo no es asi???, de casualidad tienes alguna referencia para que pueda aprender mas de eso, ya que creo que voy a seguir haciendo uso de la base de datos pero seria con otras tablas que pondre en el futuro, por ahora solo se trabaja con una tabla, pero creo que se puede complicar mas no?, de nuevo agradezco tu ayuda ha sido muy explicita y clara.

Comment: Con lo de sobrecarga me refiero a que la query a la BD en si es costosa dado que requiere ordenar la columna, al usar la propiedad (segunda forma) cada vez que se hace `self.folio` se lleva a cabo la consulta (se ejecuta la función `folio`).  Esto podría interesarte o no, la principal ventaja es que no tienes que incrementar o decrementar `self.folio` explícitamente cada vez que agregues o elimines algo, siempre que accedes al atributo se consulta a la BD y se trae el mayor valor +1 que contiene la columna folio. En el primer ejemplo solo se consulta a la BD una vez en el constructor.

Comment: En cuanto a lo segundo, `fetchone` obtiene solo el primer resultado retornado por la consulta, mientras que `fechall` obtiene una lista con todos. `fechall` tiene un uso limitado en Python, porque generalmente es más apropiado y eficiente iterar sobre el cursor (`for row in cursor:` ) y evitar crear una lista en memoria con todos los resultados (la cual puede ser enorme).

Comment: En cuanto a recursos, lo primero la [documentación oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html), aunque en inglés está muy bien y trae muchos ejemplo simplificados. Después puedes buscar recursos online sobre sqlite o sql en general para profundizar en este sistema de gestión de bd, como http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/.

Answer (score 0):

Despues de pensarle encontre la respuesta la dejo para que alguien la llegue a necesitar aunque mi pregunta ahora es como sacar el 1er numero de esa tupla XD

```
    self.orden_servicio()
    self.message1['text'] = '{}'.format(self.folio) 

   def orden_servicio(self):
         query = 'SELECT * FROM paciente ORDER BY folio DESC LIMIT 1'
         db_row = self.run_query(query)
         db_row = tuple(db_row)
         print(db_row(0))
         self.folio = db_row(0)
```

self.folio es una tupla y me da este resultado 
(4, 'Alex Rincon', 'Tuxpan 25', 45, 'Femenino', 'COPROPARASITOSCOPICO EN SERIE DE 3', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', '2019-06-24', '25, Jun, 2019', 'AOB', 'N/A', 150.0, 0.0, 174.0, 0.0)

mi pregunta es como saco el numero 4 XD???? para que sea solo